# Casting char array to uint8_t

Tags: c++, arrays, arduino, char, arduino-c++

I have a function definition like this in an Arduino library:

```
bool RHReliableDatagram::sendtoWait(uint8_t * buf, uint8_t len, uint8_t address)
```

When I use:

```
uint8_t timePacket[] = "time\n";
sendtoWait(timePacket, sizeof(timePacket), SERVER_ADDRESS)
```

I get a perfectly fine string with "time" at the other end (SERVER_ADDRESS) in pyserial's readline() function which is decoded perfectly using utf-8 encoding.

Now I need to send some bytes using the same `sendtoWait()` function. I first define a char array of 60 bytes

```
char packetBuff[60] = "";
```

Then I get every byte and cast it as a char

```
char value = (char)flash.readByte(dumpCounter++);
```

Then put each value in the char array like this:

```
packetBuff[charNo] = value;
```

After I find a new line character I try to send the char array again using the `sendtoWait()` function:

```
if (value == '\n') {
    Serial.println(packetBuff);
    uint8_t buff[charNo];
    for (int i = 0; i < charNo; i++) {
        buff[i] = packetBuff[i];
    }
    sendtoWait(buff, charNo, SERVER_ADDRESS))
charNo++;
```

But although `Serial.println(packetBuff)` shows the proper characters e.g. something like "1559105487\n" (unix timestamp), `buff` array is just not working correctly and shows random characters something like a semi-colon, random single digit numbers etc.

How do I properly cast the char array and send it properly using the `sendtoWait()` function like "time\n" was sent?

**EDIT:**
Full code:

```
  int charNo = 0;
  char packetBuff[60] = "";
  if (dumpCounter != 0) {
    dumpCounter--;
  }
  while(dumpCounter < currentFlashLoc) {
    char value = (char)flash.readByte(dumpCounter++);
    packetBuff[charNo] = value;
    if (value == '\n') {
      Serial.println(packetBuff);
      uint8_t buff[charNo];
      for (int i = 0; i < charNo; i++) {
        buff[i] = packetBuff[i];
      }
      if (manager.sendtoWait(buff, charNo, SERVER_ADDRESS)) {
        // packet sent successfully
      }
      charNo = -1;
    }
    charNo++;
  }
```

Comment: Looks like C++ to me, not C.

Comment: Use `uint8_t` everywhere there instead of `char`. Done.

Comment: @DYZ this is again the fault of the Arduino, which has *really appalling* docs that call the language "C/C++" and such...

Comment: Why are you copying your buffer byte by byte? If you have a `char` array, just cast it as a whole to `uint8_t*` and send away.

Comment: It would be better to post the code that is not working,  instead of a series of partial snippets with english text interleaved

Comment: Is `charNo++` inside the `if ( value == '\n' ) { ` ... `}` block?

Comment: @M.M full code posted and no its outside the block

Comment: You don't actually copy the `\n` to the buffer because you copy to the buffer before incrementing `charNo`

Comment: Also why don't you just send `packetBuff` and not bother with `buff`

Comment: Yes @M.M thanks for pointing that out. I tried to first send the `packetBuff` directly but did not properly cast it like @n.m. suggested above. I have gotten rid of `buff` and used `(uint8_t*)` to cast it. It works perfectly. Thanks :) After all that was the question in the first place

Comment: You are not null-terminating packetBuf, so println is likely to print garbage.

Answer (score 2):

Casting the char array like this:

```
sendtoWait((uint8_t*)packetBuff, sizeof(packetBuff), SERVER_ADDRESS)
```

works correctly. `buff` is not required.